# Heroku app not working on mobile Safari

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, safari

I've built a web app on a MEAN stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) and I run it through Heroku. When I access the application on my computer through Google Chrome everything works great (although rather slowly). However, when I access the application on my iPhone through mobile Safari barely anything works. Links on the home page only appear sometimes, nothing appears on the sub pages.

The app lives at http://mobseen.it

Any idea why Chrome would work well but mobile Safari would work so poorly, and what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've surfed your site from both my computer and my phone(which worked fine albeit a bit slow). After analyzing it briefly in Chrome as well as [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bjMcy/http://mobseen.it/), I think you're problems are coming from the amount of resources the device is pulling in and processing. Take a look at some of the recommendations on pingdom and go from there.

I would also try setting it up on OpenShift to see if it's any better.

Comment: Thanks @enolam, this helped me identify the major problem. I'm pulling in each Stadium from my Stadia API in order to display stadium name, city, colors, etc. The problem is that several of these stadiums contain a photos array with thousands of 'photo' objects. This is slowing down the loading of my home page. I need to pull in only the pieces of the stadium object I need (name, city, colors, etc.) rather than pulling in the entire object.